# 960gs and backgrounds for margins

Tags: css, 960.gs

I'm developing a site using 960gs and I'm running into some troubles. I want to display a small (beveled) border between my columns. One way (i'm using now) is to give the main container a background-image, but this means I have to manually make images for 2, 3 or more columns. I rather set a background to the columns themselves, but this would mean that I have to get rid of the margin. What would be the neatest approach to handle this?

Thanks,
J.

Answer (score 0):

go to the 960.gs site and click generate css. u can then edit the column width there and make the columns a little smaller to accommodate the bevel width on both sides

Answer (score 0):

Yes, avoid using images whenever possible, specially for things like this. If for example, you have 3 columns, 300px each, 30px of margin between them:

```
column 1 - 300px wide
```

---

```
column 2 - 300px wide, margin:0 30px (left and right = 30)
```

---

```
column 3 - 300px wide
```

Just change the rules a bit and give that central column the borders, for example

```
column2 {border-left:1px dashed #ccc; border-right:1px dashed #ccc; margin:0 29px;}
```

By reducing the margin by 1 px you make space for the space now taken up by the borders